# Free C# 3D engine that can display output for 3D glasses

Tags: gratis, c#

I was searching for a free 3D engine for C# during the last few weeks, and I found one on the following website: [www.drawing3d.de/](http://www.drawing3d.de/)

It works fine, but I need to show my output as an animation, which uses a 3d effects like a red/blue filter, so that I can view it with 3d glasses (anaglyph glasses).

The framework should, if possible, be very easy to use. My scene should only show spheres which I can move around in the three dimensional room. They should also have different colors. Optimum would be an option to turn the 3d filter effect on and off, so that you can view the animation with and without glasses, too. But this is not a main criterion.

The engine should be usable in C# (WPF or WindowsForms). Does anyone know of a free 3D engine which I could use?